# How to compare two value that has same property of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, compare

I have two data below:

```
const data1 = 
[
  {
    "Name": "Shoes",
    "SKU": "SKU001",
    "Quantity": 4
  },
  {
    "Name": "Sweater",
    "SKU": "SKU002",
    "Quantity": 2
  }
]
const data2 =
[
  {
    "DN": "DN0001",
    "SKU": "SKU001",
    "Quantity": 4
  },
  {
    "DN": "DN0002",
    "SKU": "SKU002",
    "Quantity": 4
  }
]
```

I want to compare the quantity of each SKU data1 with the quantity of each SKU data2 ( the same or not). How I can compare that?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: expected output:
Quantity of SKU001 of data1 === Quantity of SKU001 of data2 (true) ;

Quantity of SKU002 of data1 === Quantity of SKU002 of data2 (false)

Comment: Do you mean you want to compare the values of `Quantity` property in each object which has the same value in `SKU` property? If that's the case, what is indeed the wanted result? A simple array of booleans, or maybe an object containing more information?

Comment: One by one using a specific reference, or all at once?

Comment: Yes. thats what I mean. simple array of boolean is ok

Comment: All at once....

Comment: Okay, now we know what you need. But, the question became a bit problematic. At first, it lacks your attempt to resolve your problem, and secondly, editing it to really ask what you need invalidates the existing answer. I'd suggest you to try something on your own, and if that is not going to work, ask a new question. If you end up to a new question, please add your attempt to the question, and be much more specific when describing your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like below

```
const data1 =
    [
        {
            "Name": "Shoes",
            "SKU": "SKU002",
            "Quantity": 4
        },
        {
            "Name": "Sweater",
            "SKU": "SKU002",
            "Quantity": 2
        }
    ]
const data2 =
    [
        {
            "DN": "DN0001",
            "SKU": "SKU001",
            "Quantity": 4
        },
        {
            "DN": "DN0002",
            "SKU": "SKU002",
            "Quantity": 4
        }
    ]

const result = data1.map((list) => {
    const hasItem = data2.find((data) => data.SKU === list.SKU);
    if (hasItem) {
        return hasItem.Quantity === list.Quantity;
    } else {
        return false
    }

})

console.log('res', result); // [true, false]
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const data1 = 
[
  {
    "Name": "Shoes",
    "SKU": "SKU001",
    "Quantity": 4
  },
  {
    "Name": "Sweater",
    "SKU": "SKU002",
    "Quantity": 2
  }
]
const data2 =
[
  {
    "DN": "DN0001",
    "SKU": "SKU001",
    "Quantity": 4
  },
  {
    "DN": "DN0002",
    "SKU": "SKU002",
    "Quantity": 4
  }
]

let result = data1.map(d1 => data2.find(d2 => d2.SKU === d1.SKU)?.Quantity === d1.Quantity);

console.log(result);
```